# Book where the main character gives a powerful sword to one of his friends which causes someone to betray him

Tags: story-identification, novel

Don't remember a whole lot about this book, but I recall it was very long. Like over 1000 pages. The main protagonist got a really powerful sword and gave it to one of his friends, which then caused someone else to betray him, kill all his friends, take the sword and the main character ends up in slavery or something similar.

He ends up meeting someone powerful who he tells about what happened to him so he brings the guy who betrayed the main character. This is probably the part I remember best, he says apologize, so the main character starts apologizing and then he says something along the lines of "no not you" which means he believed the main character and he gets his sword back.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any other details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Some of this sounds like the Way of Kings by Brandon Sanderson, but maybe with parts of Words of Radiance, the sequel, mixed in.

Comment: @kjw could possibly be Dragonsteel also, if OP happened to attend Brigham Young. I haven't read Dragonsteel, but "like Way of Kings + Words of Radiance in a single volume" doesn't have a lot of other options...

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like the [Way of Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_of_Kings) by Brandon Sanderson.  It is a very long book.

> The main character, Kaladin, kills a shardbearer, which according to tradition, means he gets the shards.  He doesn't want the status of owning the Armor and Sword, & gives them to a squad mate. His army commander, Amaram, takes the shards and kills Kaladin's squad mates and sends Kaladin into slavery.

In the second book, [Words of Radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_of_Radiance)

> Kaladin is speaking with Dalinar, one of the most powerful men on the planet, and tells him about the earlier betrayal. This doesn't go well for Kaladin at first, since Dalinar is friends with Amaram, but by the end of the book, Amaram's duplicitous nature is revealed and Dalinar asks him to apologize. Here's the quote:
>  
>  
>  Dalinar nodded to himself, as if this were all expected. "I believe an apology is due."
>  Kaladin struggled to remain upright, his leg feeling weak. So this would be his final punishment. Apologizing to Amaram in public. A humiliation above all others.
>  "I-" Kaladin began.
>  "Not you, son," Dalinar said softly.
>  
>  
>  Although, Kaladin doesn't get *that* sword back.

Comment: "Shards" = Powered armor plus a "makes lightsaber look like a butter knife" type sword